# Angular material make sidenav modal

Tags: angularjs, modal-dialog, angular-material

I am new using angular material and i have a question about the possibility to put a sidenav modal,

Today i tried to use the sidenav it works perfectly but i need another option, i want to disallow the closure of this sidenav using 'esc' from keyboard or clicking out the sidenav.

Here is an exemple with the sidenav by default.
[CODEPEN EXAMPLE](http://codepen.io/anon/pen/ZGJrvM)

```
//Javascript : from codepen
angular.module('MyApp').controller('AppCtrl', function ($scope,$timeout, $mdSidenav, $mdUtil, $log) {    
$scope.toggleRight = buildToggler('right');

/**
 * Build handler to open/close a SideNav; when animation finishes
 * report completion in console
 */
function buildToggler(navID) {      
  var debounceFn =  $mdUtil.debounce(function(){
        $mdSidenav(navID)
          .toggle()
          .then(function () {
            $log.debug("toggle " + navID + " is done");
          });
      },300);
  return debounceFn;
}})
.controller('RightCtrl', function ($scope, $timeout, $mdSidenav, $log) {
backdrop : 'static',
$scope.close = function () {
  $mdSidenav('right').close()
    .then(function () {
      $log.debug("close RIGHT is done");
    });
};
});
```

I found "backdrop:static" and "keyboard:false" options but it doesn't work. Or i don't know how to do it.

If somebody know a solution it will be cool !

Answer (score 0):

You can set the md-is-locked-open attribute after the sidenav is opened. E.g. use a scope flag in your event handler:

```
function buildToggler(navID) {      
  var debounceFn =  $mdUtil.debounce(function(){
    $mdSidenav(navID)
      .toggle()
      .then(function () {
        $scope.isLockedOpen = true;
      });
  },300);
...
```

and then in your template use sth like

```
<md-sidenav class="md-sidenav-right" md-component-id="right" md-is-locked-open="isLockedOpen">
```

Comment: Hi and thanks for your replay :) I tried it and it works but there is still a problem : When i put isLockedOpen value to true, the sidenav is not anymore fixed top :s Is this a normal behavior?

Comment: sorry for coming back that late - did you resolve your issue? What do you mean with "not anymore fixed top"?

Comment: No problem ;) i have a navbar top and the slider override this navbar then if i put the isLockedOpen to true my sidebar is set just below my navbar. I don't know if that is well explained ^^

Comment: I made it but well isLockedOpen is not the good option. ... The behavior is not the one i need i will try with a div with background transparent instead.

Answer (score 0):

sorry for making an answer that late ...

I just forgot two braces in the last code line :

},300); become },300)();

```
function buildToggler(navID) {      
    var debounceFn =  $mdUtil.debounce(function(){
    $mdSidenav(navID)
    .toggle()
    .then(function () {
        $scope.isLockedOpen = true;
    });
},300)();
```